# Run PhantomJS by batch

Tags: command-line, batch

I got a question regarding creating a batch file that calls the phantomjs application and use two files.

Overview of files:

- phantomjs application in: **`I:/path/to/my/file/test/phantomjs`**
- phantomjs runnerfile in **`I:/path/to/my/file/test/runner.js`**
- testfile  in **`I:/path/to/my/file/unit/testfile.js`**

How can I accomplish a batch file that does the following:

```
phantomjs runner.js file:///I:/path/to/my/file/unit/SpecRunner.html
```

Because when I run my batch it says that it can not find the file (running from C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe)

Can anyone perhaps guide me how I could achieve this

Answer (score 1):

```
"path-to-\phantomjs.exe" "path-to-\runner.js" "I:\path\to\my\file\unit\SpecRunner.html"
```